# Optimize a 'groupby' with 'apply' in pandas with a large dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a large Dataframe `poc_merged` (about 6 milion records) and I calculate an "history" for each distinct pair of columns `('poc2_56_DEBITORE','poc3_53_DT_DIST')` and add this information as new columns.

**Problem**

The distinct pair of columns are about 5 milion instances and this implies running the `.apply()` about 5 milion times, making the execution too slow (different days). How could I
optimize the function in `.apply()` method? Thank you very much!

**Code**

```
def get_ratio_impagato(eff_es):
    num_transazioni = eff_es.size 
    ratio_impagato = 100*eff_es[eff_es == 'IMPAGATO'].count()/num_transazioni 
    return ratio_impagato, num_transazioni  

def calculate_aggregate(x, prefix_col, col_agg, trim):
    x_init, x, sum_imp_trim = x.copy(True), x.iloc[0], 0
    # Get history for each pair ('poc2_56_DEBITORE','poc3_53_DT_DIST') in trimesters
    eff_prec_debit = poc_merged_deb_cred[ (poc_merged_deb_cred[col_agg] == x[col_agg]) & (poc_merged_deb_cred['poc3_EF_SCADENZA'] < x['poc3_53_DT_DIST'])]
    for i_trim in range(1,trim+1):
        start_date = x['poc3_53_DT_DIST'] - pd.DateOffset(months=(i_trim-1)*3)
        last_date = x['poc3_53_DT_DIST'] - pd.DateOffset(months=i_trim*3)     
        eff_prec_debit_cumulato = eff_prec_debit[ eff_prec_debit['poc3_53_DT_DIST'] >= last_date ] 
        eff_prec_debit_trim = eff_prec_debit_cumulato[eff_prec_debit_cumulato['poc3_53_DT_DIST']<start_date]  

        # Columns to append to the current group of rows
        x_init[prefix_col+'_ratio_imp_'+str(i_trim)], x_init[prefix_col+'_num_trans_'+str(i_trim)] = get_ratio_impagato(eff_prec_debit_trim.poc3_EF_ESITO_EFF) 
        sum_imp_trim += x_init[prefix_col+'_ratio_imp_'+str(i_trim)]
        if i_trim > 1:
            x_init[prefix_col+'_ratio_imp_cum_'+str(i_trim)], x_init[prefix_col+'_num_trans_cum_'+str(i_trim)] = get_ratio_impagato(eff_prec_debit_cumulato.poc3_EF_ESITO_EFF)  

    x_init[prefix_col+'_media_trim_imp'] = sum_imp_trim/trim
    return x_init

# Apply function on groupby
poc_merged_deb_cred = poc_merged.groupby(by=['poc2_56_DEBITORE','poc3_53_DT_DIST']).apply(lambda x: calculate_aggregate(x, 'deb','poc2_56_DEBITORE', trim=3))
```

`poc_merged_deb_cred` is a subset of `poc_merged` and they have the following dtypes:

```
poc3_53_DT_DIST             datetime64[ns]
poc3_EF_IMP_EFF                    float64
poc3_EF_SCADENZA            datetime64[ns]
poc3_EF_ESITO_EFF                   object
poc1_58_CODICE_CREDITORE            object
poc2_56_DEBITORE                    object
```

**Sample Input/Output**

Input Dataframe is `poc_merged`:

- [Input samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssCek.png)

```
        poc3_53_DT_DIST poc3_EF_IMP_EFF poc3_EF_SCADENZA    poc3_EF_ESITO_EFF   poc1_58_CODICE_CREDITORE    poc2_56_DEBITORE
6240393 16/06/2021      536.71          11/07/2021          PAGATO              8887318558                  8888840499
6208020 10/06/2021      2499.37         09/07/2021          PAGATO              8889494443                  8888840499
6166285 09/06/2021      1084.96         04/07/2021          PAGATO              8887318558                  8888840499
6159911 09/06/2021      2313.94         05/07/2021          PAGATO              8889494443                  8888840499
6153921 08/06/2021      19712.10        30/06/2021          PAGATO              8889306572                  8888840499
```

Output Dataframe is always `poc_merged`:

- [Output sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iq3h1.png), where for each group in *(poc3_53_DT_DIST, poc2_56_DEBITORE)* assign same output calculated by `.apply()` function:

```
        poc3_53_DT_DIST poc3_EF_IMP_EFF poc3_EF_SCADENZA    poc3_EF_ESITO_EFF   poc1_58_CODICE_CREDITORE    poc2_56_DEBITORE    deb_ratio_imp_1 deb_num_trans_1 deb_ratio_imp_2 deb_num_trans_2 deb_ratio_imp_cum_2 deb_num_trans_cum_2 deb_ratio_imp_3 deb_num_trans_3 deb_ratio_imp_cum_3 deb_num_trans_cum_3 deb_media_trim_imp
6240393 16/06/2021      536.71          11/07/2021          PAGATO              8887318558                  8888840499          0.00            168             0.00            361             0.00                529                 0.62            321             0.24                850                 0.21
6208020 10/06/2021      2499.37         09/07/2021          PAGATO              8889494443                  8888840499          0.00            163             0.00            386             0.00                549                 0.67            300             0.24                849                 0.10
6166285 09/06/2021      1084.96         04/07/2021          PAGATO              8887318558                  8888840499          0.00            156             0.00            385             0.00                541                 0.67            300             0.24                841                 0.26
6159911 09/06/2021      2313.94         05/07/2021          PAGATO              8889494443                  8888840499          0.00            156             0.00            385             0.00                541                 0.67            300             0.24                841                 0.26
6153921 08/06/2021      19712.10        30/06/2021          PAGATO              8889306572                  8888840499          0.00            162             0.00            379             0.00                541                 0.65            306             0.24                847                 0.00
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample (small) data and expected output?

Comment: Hi, @AndrejKesely I've just added it.

Comment: Please don't put the data  as images (we cannot copy-and-paste data from them). Can you put the data as text (with correct formatting)?